# Improve performance of JS - Avoid selecting element with same ID more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a function that does something like this:

```
function my_function() {
  if ($('#footer').outerHeight() > 100) {
  $('#footer').height(...) ;
  $('#footer').css(....) ;
}
```

That function is called everytime I scroll, so I wonder if it's that bad to do this $('#footer') so many times. If so, what would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: maybe you can cache the return value? this question is trivial.

Comment: If performance is the final goal, use pure javascript, not jquery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should chain your functions and cache your selector like so:

```
function my_function() {
  var footer = $('#footer');
  if (footer.outerHeight() > 100) {
      footer.height(...).css(....);
  }
}
```

You could even move the `var footer = $('#footer');` outside of the function making it global to further improve it.

Comment: But that would create a "var footer" for each scroll, right? Shouldn't I add the dollar in front of it? var $footer?

Comment: It would reselect the variable yes, but as I mentioned you could create the footer variable as a global one to prevent reassigning it all the time.

Comment: This: `$('#footer')` - is a jQuery object, using a variable as in my example has the same effect

Answer (score 4):

I thing you need a solution like this to improve the Performance.

[How to improve the performance of your java script in your page?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-java-script-in-your-page/)

[What are the common jQuery pitfalls to avoid?](http://jqfaq.com/jquery-pitfalls/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var $footer;
function my_function() {
    $footer = $footer || $('#footer');
    if ($footer.outerHeight() > 100) {
        $footer.height(...) ;
        $footer.css(....) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but if you don't want your if statement evaluated at all (past the first time), try the following:

```
var $footer;
var footerEvaled = false;
function my_function() {
if(footerEvaled == false)
{
   $footer = $footer || $('#footer');
    if ( $footer.outerHeight() > 100) {
         $footer.height(...) ;
         $footer.css(....) ;
         footerEvaled = true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement, however it is not recommended:

```
function my_function() {
    with ($("#footer")) {
        if (outerHeight() > 100) {
            height(...).css(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store $('#footer') in a variable before the function. For example:

```
var footerHTML = $('#footer');
function my_function() {
  if ( footerHTML.outerHeight() > 100) {
  footerHTML.height(...) ;
  footerHTML.css(....) ;
}
```

This will avoid creating multiple JQuery instances for the same element.